# Плавающий блок

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать плавающий блок на jQuery или просто JS. Желаемый мною блок можно увидеть на [reformal.ru](http://reformal.ru/) (слева). так же условием является то, что блок должен состоять только из картинки (не как на reformal.ru). а в остальном идентичным (положение на экране, плавучасть и т.д.). В js не разбираюсь совсем. Заранее благодарен. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это обычная кнопка с абсолютным позиционированием + модальное окно. Как кнопку сделать, я думаю, что объяснять не надо, а плагинов по модальным окнам в инете пруд пруди. Вот например [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/), который, как мне кажется, у них и используется

Comment: вы не правильно меня поняли. модальное окно меня не интересует. меня интересует сама плавающая кнопка с её позиционированием.

Comment: Я когда-то делал пример, похожий на ваш. [Посмотрите](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/rzfF7/1/), как можно реализовать

Comment: из эстетических соображаений я бы ещё easing добавил, а так очень здорово

Comment: Согласен, но когда делаешь кому-то пример на скорую руку, да еще и спешишь по своим делам, то мелочи пропускаются.

Comment: спасибо за помощь)